# Access Flask session with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I have a Python Flask server serving not only an webapp but also a set of routes, sort of like an API.

In this webapp, I'm using only ReactJS, as in the HTML code is simply a div and ReactJS puts everything in place from there.

Only problem is: Flask is taking care of the login process, which means only Flask has access to the credentials of the user and the result of the login. For the ReactJS interface to work properly, it needs an ID (most likely a huge string) of the user and other additional info. I could easily stash that info on Flask's session, but how can ReactJS read it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think two most common approaches are to either pass it with some initial data from the HTML (`<script>window.initialData = {userId: {{ current_user.id }}};</script>` sort of code; consider worrying about the proper escaping there) or implement an HTTP API that allows to look up currently authenticated user and fetch this data when your React app starts up.

Comment: You mean use Jinja2 to insert hidden fields containing the information? That could work... But how secure would it be?

Comment: @drdaeman ? (forgot to mention you)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My suggestion is to pass data using Jinja2 templates. It could be anything (e.g. `<meta>` tags or even a hidden `<div>`), but I would suggest a `<script>` tag with initial data. E.g. something in spirit of

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.initialData = {{ initial_data|tojson }};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/your-react-app/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `initial_data` contains all your React app need to know, e.g. username, profile picture URL, new notifications flag, etc.

This data is only for React app to know what server thinks of you. I.e. showing a login page if you aren't logged in, or greeting the user correctly. As long as both JS and HTML (template) code is under your control, this is as secure as rendering a static page with this information. As there are no issues with rendering "`You're logged in as {{ current_user.username }}`", neither there are with those. Of course, any user can change this - by editing HTML or JS respectively - but this is would be a purely cosmetic, client-side-only hack.

An alternative would be to implement some API endpoints, e.g. `/api/whoami` and query those on React app initialization. The upside is, you don't need any templating (your HTML can be completely static), the downside is, you need to send an extra HTTP request and wait for response before you can show end-user the final page. From the security viewpoint, it's essentially the same as the JS-in-HTML method above, just that the transport differs.

Actually, normally it's both approaches mixed. Embedding is to avoid extra round-trip on the first page load, and API is to get updates after your app believes the state should've changed (e.g. after user presses the "logout" button).

When you're sending requests to your server (form submissions, XHR/AJAX API requests or anything else that takes user into account), never trust the client input and don't even send to the server who you think you are - but check what the session says. This means you have to make sure to pass cookies around, e.g. with `fetch` you need `fetch(url, {credentials: "same-origin"})` for the request to have cookies.

Basically, pass the data React has to know as JSON documents (via template embedding or API endpoint response), and don't let server do anything wrong if that data is modified.

Comment: That was one neat trick, too bad I can only give you 1 upvote! I spend most of my time on backend so these things still pass me by a little :/ Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is great. Do you know of any public project built around this setup that I could look at?